# Firebase Cloud Messaging limit on number of messages

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am sending push via FCM http api in JSON, i am experiencing at some time push are not being delivered to app while app was connected to internet and was active as well. we are getting success response as well from FCM server to our app server.
I am suspecting if this is not the case of messages being blocked due to messages being sent in bulk, like in this case we are sending around 1000 of push message at a time. 
I could not find any reference of such limitation so wondering what might be cause of it that i am getting success on app server from FCM but push not being delivered.